# Promise returns undefined value inside ngOnInit in Angular 8 ionic 4

Tags: angular, typescript, promise, ionic4, angular8

In my Ionic 4 angular 8 application I am using chrome extension to return tab URL. I am getting the tab URL value in function defined in service file but when invoked the service inside `ngOnInit()` I am getting undefined. Please help me to resolve this.

I want the URL value to be displayed in `ngOnInit()`

Inside service file

```
async chromeCall() {
    try {          
      const results = await chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function (tabs) {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, { from: 'popup', subject: 'DOMInfo' }, (response) => {
          console.info("Tab ID:", tabs[0].id);
          this.CurrentPgUrl = response.webPgURL;
          console.log(this.CurrentPgUrl);//geting value here
          return this.CurrentPgUrl;
        });
      });
    }
    catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      console.log("comes to error ");          
    }
  }
```

Inside `ngOnit()`

```
 ngOnInit(){
    this.apiService.chromeCall()
    .then(result => {
      this.url=result;
      console.log(this.url)//value undefined
 )};
```

Comment: Do you mean `this.CurrentPgUrl` is `undefined` when you log it?

Comment: Instead of using `function(tabs) {...}`, I'd recommend using `(tabs) => {...}`. This is because `function` creates a new scope, so `this` won't refer to the same thing anymore.

Comment: I'm not sure that's the issue you have, but it might be

Comment: Yes, I need this.currentPgurl in ngOnit().But now I am getting undefined

Comment: Did you try using the fat arrow (`=>`) instead of `function`?

Comment: That's mostly beside the point. The main issue is, `chromeCall` _doesn't return anything_ (the return statement there is not a return from `chromeCall`, it's a return from callback inside callback inside `chromeCall`, and is ignored).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`chromeCall` must return a promise - or anything, really, as it is written it's returning undefined. `chrome.tabs.query` is build with the callback recipe, not the promise recipe, so `await`ing it won't do anything worthy of notice.

It should go something like this:

```
chromeCall() {
    return new Promise(
        (resolve, reject) => chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, tabs => {
// dive into the callback hell here, and on the final line...
            resolve(this.CurrentPgUrl);
        }
// and the appropriate number of closing `}`s
```

Alternatively, you might use a library that promisifies those methods. This one, for example, looks like it would do the job:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/chrome-extension-async

Comment: Getting the value as expected. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this, Here we are using a promise so after getting the expected result from chrome tabs we are resolving the promise so you will not get `undefined`. I hope it helps you out.

```
async chromeCall() {
    try {

      const results = await chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function (tabs) {
   return new Promise(resolve => {
          chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, { from: 'popup', subject: 'DOMInfo' }, 
          (response) => {
             console.info("Tab ID:", tabs[0].id);
             this.CurrentPgUrl = response.webPgURL;
             console.log(this.CurrentPgUrl);//geting value here
             resolve (this.CurrentPgUrl);
        });
      });
   });     
    }
    catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      console.log("comes to error ");

    }
  }
```

**ngOnInit**

```
 ngOnInit(){
    this.apiService.chromeCall()
    .then(result =>{
    this.url=result;
    console.log(this.url)//value undefined
    )};
```

Comment: Still I am getting undefined in ngOnInit().

Comment: @SRI did you try to write `await` before the `function(tabs) { ... }` ?

Answer (score -1):

option 1 : You can put async await concept for ngOnInit method which is like this,

```
async ngOnInit(){
    let serviceResponse = await this.apiService.chromeCall();
     if(serviceResponse){
       this.url=result;
     }
 }
```

option 2: You can add if condition in side then call back method, which is like this,

```
ngOnInit(){
    console.log('Loading start')
    this.apiService.chromeCall()
    .then(result =>{
        if(result){
            this.url=result;
            console.log('Loading ends')
            console.log(this.url)
            return
        }
        console.log('Loading ends')
    ).catch(err) => {
        console.log('Loading ends', err);
    }
};
```